# How to calculate the risk free value of LP Tokens

Tags: solidity, uniswap

Question is simple but the answer might not be.

I'm looking to derive at an exact value of how much an LP Token is worth inside a solidity smart contract in a safe an effective manner. this number would be used for financial transactions so has to be free of bugs. If anyone can help or point me to the right resources you'd be doing me a huge favor, thank you so much for your time.

Comment: A starting point would be the price of the assets in the pool, but as any token the price is given by the free market, if the assets aren't valuables it probably will be below the starting point. I don't think there's an exact formula that will work for all LP tokens.

Comment: In the case of OlympusDAO, the risk free value of lp tokens is `2sqrt(n_0*n_1)`. This makes sense since the only price that is risk free is when the two tokens are both valued at $1. That is exactly `2sqrt(k)=2sqrt(n_0*n_1)` given `k=n_0*n_1` at any time.

Comment: I wonder if an aforementioned formua exists for other lp tokens.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by risk-free in this case?